# Making Directories and sub-directories - VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm writing a script in Access 2013 for work, I'm kinda of a neat freak with computers so I want to be able to output the data to a organized archive so over the years it will be, well, organized.

I know how to create a simple directory, but I want to create directories within directories.

This is my variable I have written for the path

```
strOutPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\MeijingOutput\" & MonthName(Month(Date)) & _
"_" & DatePart("YYYY", Date) & "\" & DatePart("m", Date) & "." & DatePart("d", Date) & "." & DatePart("yyyy", Date) & "\"
```

this comes out to be `C:\Users\[user]\Documents\MeijingOutput\June_2015\6.24.2015\`

Before, I was just outputting them all to the same folder "MeijingOutPut", and it worked since I was just making a new top level directory.

Is there a way I can get this code to work without having to manually check for each sub directory?

```
If Len(Dir(strOutPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then ' make the folder if it doesnt exist
MkDir strOutPath
End If
```

Comment: I got the same problem some times ago, but I didn't look for a work around... In my opinion a "simple" split/loop should do the trick! ;)

Comment: It doesn't work because it's looking for the very last directory "6.24.2015", It can't fint it if the month directory don't exist, also if the output directory doesn't exist... And your right, I didnt need the extra "\"

Comment: I was trying to do it in one go. Because If I deploy this back to the people in Meijing, I want it to create the directories, because I know they won't have them to start with

Answer (score 1):

I have finally solved it, I did in fact have to manually check each directory. I used a loop and array though to make it seem simple

```
strOutPut(0) = CurrentProject.Path & "\MeijingOutput\"
strOutPut(1) = strOutPut(0) & MonthName(Month(Date)) & "_" & DatePart("YYYY", Date) & "\"
strOutPut(2) = strOutPut(1) & DatePart("m", Date) & "." & DatePart("d", Date) & "." & DatePart("yyyy", Date)
strOutPath = strOutPut(2)
```

And the main attraction

```
 For i = 0 To 2
   If Len(Dir(strOutPut(i), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then ' make the folder if it doesnt exist
    MkDir strOutPut(i)
   End If
 Next i
```